# If $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable with $f(a)=f(b)$, $f'_{+}(a), f'_{-}(b)\gt 0$, there is $c\in (a,b)$ with $f'(c)\leq 0 = f(c)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I would, if possible, to give a rigorous proof of this question

can someone help me?

Let $f: [a, b​​] \to\mathbb {R}$ a differentiable function such that
$$
 \begin{align*}
f(a)&=f(b)\\
f'(a) &= f'_{+}(a)>0,\\
f'(b) &= f'_{-}(b)>0.
\end{align*}
$$
Prove that there exists $c\in (a,b​​)$ such that $f(c) = 0$ and $f '(c) \le 0. $

Comment: do you want $f(a)=f(b)=0$?

Comment: no i want only $f(c)$, and is $f(a)=f(b)$ and no $f(a)=f(b)=0$

Comment: this is simply not true without any additional assumption. Just look at $\sin(x) + 2$ on $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: You cannot guarantee such a $c$: given any differentiable function $f$, let $m$ be its minimum (exists, since $f$ is continuous on a finite closed interval). Then $g(x)=f(x)+2|m|+1$ satisfies the hypothesis of the claim, but it is always positive so there is no $c$ with $g(c)=0$.

Comment: derivable not differentiable ... i'm sorry!

Comment: I'm sorry, but: what's the difference, and how does it affect the proposed examples? (I am assuming that "derivable" is a term of art with which I am not familiar, so perhaps you can enlighten me)

Comment: Sorry, but since I write ITALY probably, indeed certainly do a bit of difficulty with the language .... for so mean a differentiable function such that admits $ f '(x) $ ....

Comment: @FrConnection: We say a function $f$ is "differentiable on $[a,b]$" if $f'(c)$ exists for every $c$ in $(a,b)$, and the one-sided derivatives $f'_+(a)$ and $f'_-(b)$ both exist. Is that what you mean? If so, look at the counterexamples given by Thomas and myself.

Comment: yes it's what I mean

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem would be true only if $f(a)=f(b)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments clearly show, the given statement is false.

To produce a true statement,
you either need to assume $f(a)=f(b)=0$ in the hypothesis, or $f(c)=f(a)$ in the conclusion.

The latter case is easily reduced to the former by translation.

I'll take the liberty of stating and proving this:

**Theorem**:
If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, the appropriate one sided derivatives at the endpoints are positive, and $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then there is a $c\in(a,b)$ with $f(c)=0$ and $f'(c)\le0$.

*Proof*:
 Since the derivative from the right at $a$ exists and is positive, $f$ takes a positive value for some $e>a$. Since the derivative from the left exists at $b$  and is positive, $f$ takes a negative value for some $s$ with $e<s<b$.

By the Intermediate Value Theorem, the set $Z=\{x:f(x)=0, e<x<s\}$ is nonempty.

Let $c$ be the infimum of $Z$.  In the case that $Z$ is infinite, by the grace of the continuity of $f$, $f(c)=0$. If $Z$ is finite, we of course have $f(c)=0$.

Now note that  $f'(c)$ cannot be positive (otherwise we could find a zero of $f$ greater than e and strictly less than $c$).

Of course, since $c\in Z$, we have $a<c<b$, and we are done.

Comment: $c$  is the infimum of $Z$ and $c\in Z$ ?? $c\in(a;b)$, and so $a<c<b$